# VST forward_call fail on non-standard calling convention

Tags: c, coq, formal-verification, verifiable-c

I'm using VST 2.5 and Coq 8.11.0

Got an error while doing `forward_call` on function with non-standard calling convention.
Minimal code example:

```
struct t {
  int t_1;
  int t_2;
};

struct t test_aux() {
  struct t ret;
  ret.t_1 = 1;
  ret.t_2 = 2;
  return ret;
}

void test_f() {
  test_aux();
}
```

VST specs:

```
Require Import VST.floyd.proofauto. 
Require Import example.

Definition Vprog : varspecs. mk_varspecs prog. Defined. Instance CompSpecs : compspecs. make_compspecs prog. Defined.

Open Scope Z.

Definition aux_spec : ident * funspec :=   DECLARE _test_aux
    WITH res : val
    PRE [tptr (Tstruct _t noattr)]
      PROP ()
      PARAMS (res)
      GLOBALS ()
      SEP (data_at_ Tsh (Tstruct _t noattr) res)
    POST [tvoid]
      PROP ()
      LOCAL ()
      SEP (data_at Tsh (Tstruct _t noattr) 
                   (Vint (Int.repr 1), Vint (Int.repr 2)) res).

Definition test_spec : ident * funspec :=   DECLARE _test_f
    WITH temp : val
    PRE []
      PROP ()
      PARAMS ()
      GLOBALS ()
      SEP (data_at_ Tsh (Tstruct _t noattr) temp)
    POST [tvoid]
      PROP ()
      LOCAL ()
      SEP ().

Definition Gprog := ltac:(with_library prog [aux_spec; test_spec]).

Theorem test : semax_body Vprog Gprog f_test_f test_spec. Proof.   start_function.   Fail forward_call (nullval). Admitted.
```

Error:

```
Unable to unify  "Tfunction (Tcons (tptr (Tstruct _t noattr)) Tnil)
    tvoid cc_default" with  "Tfunction (Tcons (tptr (Tstruct _t noattr)) Tnil)
    tvoid
    {|
    cc_vararg := false;
    cc_unproto := false;
    cc_structret := true |}".
```

I don't know if this is a bug or intended behavior, so I have a few questions here:

1) Is this a bug?

2) If not, what workarounds exists to prove such cases?

UPDATE:

We ran into this problem after using the following workaround around the struct-copying restriction: we define a `struct_normalize : statement -> statement` function in Coq that replaces struct assignments with field-by-field assignments. Hence we are working under the assumption that there is no struct copy-ing in the function we are calling. That is, we can verify the `test_aux` from the example above. So the questions are:

3. Does `forward_call` fail only because `cc_structret := true` in the `test_aux` AST?
4. Given that we normalize the functions and remove stucture-copying from the bodies of the functions, is it safe to change `structret` value accordingly and proceed with the proof?

Comment: `test_f` calls `test_aux` but does nothing with the [`struct`] return. Is that a problem in the framework? Also, most of the time, the following is better: `void test_aux(struct t *ret) { ret->t_1 = 1; ret->t_2 = 2; }  void test_f(void) { struct t ret; test_aux(&ret); }` This is even more important if the `struct` has _many_ elements (e.g.) if we add `int array[5000];` to the struct definition.

Comment: This is just a minimal example, the real code, of course, is way more complicated. Unfortunately I can't modify C code that I'm verifying, so I'm searching for another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, VST does not support struct-copying, struct-passing, or struct-returning.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710135/coq-vst-internal-structure-copying/60951992).  So you can't verify this program without changing it.